# Ruby on Rails: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named 'Image.rb' to store uploaded images, a controller 'images_controller.rb' and 'static_pages_controller.rb' with action 'tournaments'. I get the following error on navigating to '/tournaments':

> ArgumentError in StaticPages#tournament
>       Showing ../static_pages/tournament.html.erb where line #9 raised:
>
> ```
> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
> Extracted source (around line #9):
> 7 This is the information bulletin for the upcoming tournament
> 8 </h2>
> 9 <%= form_for(@image, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
> 10 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
> 11 <span class="picture">
> ```

routes.rb

```
.
.
get 'tournaments' => 'static_pages#tournament'
resources :images
```

tournament.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@image, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <span class="picture">
        <h4> </h4>
        <h3>Upload a picture here!</h3>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Give it a caption.." %>
        <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
        <%= f.submit "Post picture!" %>
    </span>
<% end %>
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def tournaments
      @image = Image.new
      @images = Image.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :logged_in_user
  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    if @image.save
      flash.now[:success] = "Uploaded successfully"
      redirect_to tournaments_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to tournaments_path
    end
  end
  private
     def image_params
        params.require(:image).permit(:name, :picture)
     end  
end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
    validate  :picture_size
    private
        def picture_size
            if picture.size > 5.megabytes
                errors.add(:picture, "Should be less than 5MB.")
            end
        end
end
```

I cannot understand where I'm going wrong. Any helpful pointers to resolving this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should change your `def tournaments` method to `def tournament`

Comment: Yep, that was really careless of me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `def tournaments` method to `def tournament`

```
def tournament
  @image = Image.new
  @images = Image.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

changed action `tournaments` to `tournament`.